# After Tenant-to-Tenant Migration, users get error "Account Does Not Exist"

Tags: office365-apps, microsoft365

We just finished a tenant-to-tenant migration, some employees are struggling logging into Office apps, after the login screen pops up and they enter in their new login email, they receive the error "User account example @ abc.com does not exist from identity provider https://xxx   does not exist in tenant abc and cannot access this application.

The employees have accounts in the new tenant and are licensed. Does anyone know of a fix?

We've had them uninstall Office apps, try different logins, change backend stuff. This happens on Windows and Mac machines